# Cannot define TEXMFHOME

Tags: command-line, latex

my bashrc:

```
DOCS_PATH=${HOME}/docs
export TEXMFHOME="${HOME}/.texmf:${DOCS_PATH}/texmf"
```

I have a texmf folder in "docs", I have defined TEXMFHOME in my bashrc and the path is correct but when I cd to TEXMFHOME I get this error:

```
cd $TEXMFHOME
bash: cd: /home/user/.texmf:/home/user/docs/texmf: File or directory not found
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: you re trying to enter in 2 folders at same time, like `cd: /home/user/.texmf && cd /home/user/docs/texmf` or `cd: /home/user/docs/texmf && cd /home/user/.texmf` but the shell didn't know which command must be used at first, so it returns an error

Answer (score 2):

This

```
DOCS_PATH=${HOME}/docs
export TEXMFHOME="${HOME}/.texmf:${DOCS_PATH}/texmf"
```

adds `${HOME}` twice to `TEXMFHOME`.  Are you sure it should not be

```
export TEXMFHOME="${HOME}/.texmf/texmf"
```